# Facebook Connect on an ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, api

The only tutorial I've found so far is: http://my6solutions.com/post/2009/04/05/Integration-of-Facebook-Connect-on-ASP-NET-MVC.aspx

I tried following it but it didn't get me anywhere because it kept saying there were missing methods (I'm guessing because the edited files he gives you is edited from an old copy of the facebook connect source and they must have updated it with new methods by now)

Can anyone point me in the right direction to integrate Facebook Connect with an Asp.Net MVC application?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 3):

### .NET Facebook API Client

http://facebook.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Home

### Project Description

A .NET client library for the Facebook API that allows developers to create Facebook Applications in C# and VB.NET with support for ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks for the link! :) While the library in its current release state doesn't completely support connect, a user has posted a quick change to make that will get you going here: http://facebook.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=55635

Comment: Another note - I'm actively working on the connect integration stuff now, so keep an eye out for it in the next couple weeks.